# Email Services import attachments - BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Tags: apex-email-service, inboundservices

Here is the portion of the code which is being run :

```
 if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) 
    {

        //Map to hold the Funder Contact Role Details with Funder
        Map<Id, Program_Contact_Role__c> mapPCRsWithProgram = new Map<Id, Program_Contact_Role__c>();

        //List to hold Content versions
        List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();

       for(integer i =0, s = email.binaryattachments.size(); i < s; i++) {
        if(email.binaryAttachments[i].contentType.startsWith('text/')){

            try{

                //Get Attachment details
                List<String> attachmentSplitsByRows = new List<String>();
```

And I'm getting a 'variable does not exist : contenType' error.

Any kind of assistance or insight you can give would be very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: the incoming CSV file is not UTF-8 - how was it saved by the user?  Not all versions of excel on all platforms can save UTF-8 files if they include "special" characters

Comment: The other file was actually a .xlsx file.

Comment: There's no way apex can handle a xslx file

Comment: oh, so it has to be a .csv ? And I guess it's both files will be a problem ? The .png and .xlsx ?

Comment: Correct.  Binary representation of xlsx and png will not be UTF8. sfdcfox answer is a good way to screen.  Or put inside a try-catch.

Comment: Thanks @cripredy - now I'm just trying to figure out where to put sfdcfox's statement. I edited the above code with his line at the //NEW LINE statement. If you have any input on that also I'd appreciate it. I hate bogging down on sfdcfox for it all. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the content type before attempting this conversion:

```
for(Integer i = 0, s = email.binaryAttachments.size(); i < s; i++) {
    if(email.binaryAttachments[i].contentType.startsWith('text/')) {
        // this is a text file of some sort //
    }
}
```

Comment: oh wow - so that contentType would also include a xls or xlsx ? If so, where would be the best place to put that into the code ? Thanks @sfdcfox !

Comment: @Zoom_v XLS and XLSX are **not** text files, and cannot easily be read by Apex. The former is undocumented and nigh impossible to use, the latter requires the use of [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) to decompress the file and parse the results. You'll only be be able to easily deal with tsv and csv.

Comment: Ok - now I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate your IF into the code. Is it just a matter of putting that IF statement around the whole sections that have the 'Get Attachment Details' and 'Get Attachment Name & Body' and the system.debug statement ? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Zoom_v Right. You'll want to iterate over the list of attachments, check if the contentType matches a text file, and then proceed from there.

Comment: I put your IF statement into the code above and labeled it with //NEW LINE ENTERED HERE and ended it right after the New Attachment line. Would that accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish ? My thinking was that it would just not add a new attachment to the LIST that way...? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you one last time - I'm using the line that you gave but I get an error for no variable for the 'i' in the binaryAttachments[i]. How should I declare that ? Do I also need to declare contentType in some way ? I'm hoping it will work if I stick that line before the 'try{' line. Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it. I know these are very rookie questions.

Comment: @Zoom_v I was trying to hint that you'd do something like `for(integer i =0, s = email.binaryattachments.size(); i < s; i++) { ...`

Comment: I'm sorry, man. I guess I just need more than hints. :-) I'm now getting an error telling me the contentType variable doesn't exist. Thanks again for any help, sorry again.

Comment: @Zoom_v I edited this in to hopefully help you out.

Comment: I think that's how I already have it. I updated my original post to show you what that portion of the code looks like. I'm still getting a 'variable does not exist :contentType' error.

Comment: Can I please reach out to you one last time on this ? I've got the code in the way you are suggesting as it in my post. But I'm still getting the 'variable does not exist :contentType' error. Thanks again for any help you can give on this. I really appreciate it so much.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a contentType property for the InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment class. There is a mimeTypeSubType property. Would that work ? There is a contentType property for the EmailFileAttachment class. Is that what should be used ?

Comment: It looks like it had to be mimeTypeSubType, not contentType. Thanks again for all of your help @sfdcfox. Btw - I'm following your blog. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on your comment thread and exploiting sfdcfox's answer: (and supporting more than one attachment)

```
 global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelop){

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    for (InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttch : email.binaryAttachments != null
          ? email.binaryAttachments : new List<InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment()) {
        if (isValidCsvAttachment(binAttch)) {
           // parse CSV into objects
        }
    }
   ...

}

Boolean isValidCsvAttachment(InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttch) {
  Set<String> validCsvContentTypes = new Set<String> {'text/csv', 'text/plain' , ...};
  return validCsvContentTypes.contains(binAttch.contentType);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cropredy for taking the time to write that. I'm confused in that I'm not sure what portion needs to go within the "//parse CSV into objects" part. I think it is the portion from "// Get attachment name and body" to "firstRow = true;". Also, the portion starting with the Booleon line is even beyond the original bracket of the class. Is that correct ?

Comment: The line starting `// parse CSV into objects` is basically all of your code that works with `binAttch.body` - you don't need to create an Attachment object, you just need to convert the Blob `binAttch.body` to a string and then split into lines as you have done.  Note that your csv parser is fairly simple-minded and doesn't support cells with embedded commas or line breaks. There are github libs of apex code that do a more robust csv parsing that i'd encourage you to use

Comment: ok - I tried applying your changes to the code, but I was so confused. I think the fact that I didn't include the entire code in my original post also might have affected the way you wrote it because there are elements such as the Attachment object and the ContentVersion list which it looks like you replaced which are referred to later in part of the code which wasn't included in my original post. I've updated my original post to show you. I didn't think the solution was going to be so much of a rewrite. Thank you so much for looking at it. I appreciate it so much.

Comment: so -- my point is simply that as you process each inbound file attachment, pass it through a method to decide whether it is a CSV ... I'd strongly urge you to rethink your method `handleInboundEmail` and make it shorter, by orchestrating smaller methods that do parts of the problem